# ¿Cómo asignar Id a la llave foranea de otra tabla usando Laravel 6.0?

Tags: php, sql

Tengo una tabla de usuarios que contiene los siguientes campos:

```
Tabla Usuario:
.....................                 
id_usuario      
nombre    
apellido
rif   
edad
........................
```

Y una tabla empresa con lo siguiente:

```
Tabla Empresa:
.........................            
id_empresa     
nom_empresa   
direccion
rif
fk_IDusuario
........................
```

Ambas tablas están relacionadas, a través del campo `fk_IDusuario` y el campo `id_usuario`.

Quisiera poder hacer algún tipo de comparación entre las dos tablas de manera que al tener el mismo `rif` se le asigne el ID correspondiente a la Tabla Empresa.

Comment: Y has intentado hacer algo en PHP, podrias poner el codigo que estas probando, de esa manera podremos ayudarte

Comment: no, he estado investigando y posiblemente se hace con inner join pero no se como aplicarlo a php ya que es código sql

Comment: Osea en PHP se hace de la misma forma como lo haces con SQL, de hecho si o si debes hacer una consulta en SQL. El resultado de este lo manejas con PHP.  Documentacion: https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php

Comment: ya lo pude solucionar, logré resolverlo con este código

public function index()
    {
        $data = DB::table('incidencias')
       ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
       ->select('incidencias.rif', 'clientes_incid.cat_cliente')
       ->get();
        return view('ATC.index', compact('data'));
    }

Gracias por tu ayuda igualmente amigo

Comment: @oscar podrías "podrías publicar una respuesta" con la solución que encontraste ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = DB::table('usuario')
   ->join('empresa', 'empresa.rif', '=', 'usuario.rif')
   ->select('usuario.rif', 'empresa.nom_empresa')
   ->get();
```

Con esto logré solucionarlo

Comment: Nunca pusiste que usabas un framework, de esa manera era imposible que alguien diera con la solución. De todas maneras me alegro que hayas encontrado la respuesta